# Populating a 2D array of objects using given probability in Java

Tags: java, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

I have been given a task to create a program which models cell growth according to some given rules. To do this, I have to create a 2D array and populate it with Cell objects which are either living or dead according to a given probability. So far, I've been able to create what I *think* is an array of these objects, but I'm not sure how I would go about using the probability I've been given to assign "dead" or "normal" status to each object. This is what I've done so far (not that much I know...):

```
public class CellGrid
{
    // Store the cells of the game in this 2D array
    private Cell[][] cells;

    /**
     * Contructor for a CellGrid. Populates the grid with cells that will be
     * living and normal (with probability given by lifeChance) or dead. Cells
     * will NOT start mutated.
     * 
     * @param size
     *            the size of the grid will be size x size
     * @param lifeChance
     *            the probability of each cell starting out alive
     * @param mutationChance
     *            the probability that (when required) each cell will mutate
     */
    public CellGrid(int size, double lifeChance, double mutationChance)
    {
        Cell[][] cells = new Cell[size][size];

        //populates the array with new Cell objects
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)      
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) 
            {
                cells[i][j]= new Cell();

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a random value.

```
Random r = new Random();
double nextVal = r.nextDouble();
```

nextVal is then: 0 <= nextVal < 1

you can now set all cells where nextVal < lifeChance.
If lifeChance will be 0.1, then 10 percent of your cells will be alive.

```
...
Random r = new Random();
for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) 
{
    Cell c = new Cell();
    double nextVal = r.nextDouble();
    if(nextVal < lifeChance){
        c.setLife(true);
    } else{
        c.setLife(false);
    }
    cells[i][j]= c;
}
```

You have to change setLife() according to your class spec...

Comment: Why write `c.setLife(nextVal < lifeChance);` when you can waste 5 lines? Also `Random#nextDouble()` returns value from 0 *inclusive* to 1 exclusive, so `0 <= nextVal < 1`

Comment: Waste 5 lines to "hopefully" make it more clear. Corrected the range

Comment: with a fitting Ctor, `cells[i][j] = new Cell(new Random().nextDouble() < lifeChance);` would use only 1 line instead of 9...

Answer (score 0):

What you want is this :

```
public CellGrid(int size, double lifeChance, double mutationChance)
    {
        cells = new Cell[size][size];
        Random r = new Random();
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<size; j++) {
                double nextVal = r.nextDouble();
                if(nextVal < lifeChance){
                    cells[i][j] = new NormalCell();
                } else{
                    cells[i][j] = new DeadCell();
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

I have completed full CellGrid class implementation. Let me know if you need help.